# Explicit template function argument specification and Implicit conversion of function arguments in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

Title of the topic is long and cryptic, but question is rather simple.

I am reading `14.8.1 Explicit template argument specification` in the latest C++11 Specs draft(N3242=11-0012), page 375

> 6 Implicit conversions (Clause 4) will be performed on a function
>   argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function
>   parameter if the parameter type contains no template-parameters that
>   participate in template argument deduction. [ Note: Template
>   parameters do not participate in template argument deduction if they
>   are explicitly speciﬁed. For example,

```
template<class T> void f(T);
class Complex {
  Complex(double);
};
void g() {
  f<Complex>(1); // OK, means f<Complex>(Complex(1))
}
```

> —end note ]

Could someone explain to me, what it trying to say and where is the conversion taking place in the example.
Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion is taking place right here:

```
f<Complex>(1);
```

You are calling a function `f` that expects a `Complex`, but you are passing it an `int` instead. There is a *standard conversion* from `int` to `double` and a *user defined conversion* from `double` to `Complex`.

What the standard is trying to say is that when you *explicitly* provide template arguments to a template function, those behave as if the function was declared with those types. That is, when you call `f<Complex>` it behaves as if declared:

```
void f( Complex );
```

Otherwise, had the template parameter not being explicitly specified, `T` would have been deduced to be `int` and no implicit conversion would have taken place.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't `explicitly provide template parameters` be `explicitly provide template arguments`, since the explicit template argument <Complex> is given ? Thanks !

Comment: @newprint: Sure, why not? I never got on board of the _argument/parameter_ distinction boat... I often mix those concepts

Comment: Thanks for reply detailed reply! (I suspect that Specs writers mix arg/param terms as well)

Comment: Parameter is what something is declared to take, argument is what you actually pass in – pretty straightforward. :-]